# two 1u servers or one 2u server

Tags: dell-poweredge

I was task to propose new servers.

Given a budget that I can purchase either two 1u servers or one 2u server, which one should I go for?

eg. 1u -> server Dell R310, 2u server -> Dell R710

Any pro and con if I go for 2u server?

Answer (score 2):

You should go for what you need.

If you need two servers, buy two servers.  If you need one server, buy one server.  A server's height has no correlation with performance or appropriateness for your business's needs.

Comment: ...nor it's price either.

Comment: But on that note, give me an R710 any day. Because it sounds better than a 310 (blame Intels i-series processor namings)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I unable to answer when my superior ask me this question as I have no prior experience getting new  servers.  Shane's answer do pretty much clear up what should I go for :)